# YouTubePlayerView over a SurfaceView (CameraPreview)

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

My Activity has a YouTubePlayerView that must be shown over a SurfaceView (a Camera Preview).

However, since the video view of the YouTubePlayerView also uses a SurfaceView, the Youtube video is not shown. The controls and play button are visible, you can hear the audio while the video is being played, and when it stops, its thumbnail is visible.

I understand that the correct way to deal with this situation is to use setZOrderMediaOverlay. I am able to make it work properly with a regular VideoView over a Camera Preview. But, how can I use setZOrderMediaOverlay in the YouTubePlayerView?

Is there any solution for this problem?

Below is a stripped down version of the code:

```
package com.moahh.yc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class CameraActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private CameraPreview cameraPreview;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private final String videoId = "jNQXAC9IVRw";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this);
        relativeLayout.addView(cameraPreview);

        youTubePlayerView = new YouTubePlayerView(this);
        relativeLayout.addView(youTubePlayerView);

        youTubePlayerView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cameraPreview.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cameraPreview.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cameraPreview.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean restored) {
        if (restored) {
            youTubePlayer.play();
        } else {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
            youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    }
}
```

And the layout of the activity is only a RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I face the same issue now. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I haven't, so I changed my layout, with the YouTubePlayerView not over the Camera Preview.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved adding the view when PlayerStateChangeListener called onVideoStarted.

```
youTubePlayerView.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

           @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {
                cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this);
                relativeLayout.addView(cameraPreview);
            }
            [...]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem..
Try to initiate the `CameraPreview` after you initiate the YouTube view.
means in the `onInitializationSuccess` like so:

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean restored) {
    if (restored) {
        youTubePlayer.play();
        cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this);
        relativeLayout.addView(cameraPreview);        
} else {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
        youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not seem to work.  It will only be executed when 'restored' is true, so the camera will not be instantiated when the activity is first created. And, if you instantiate the camera when 'restored' is false, the whole YouTubePlayerView will lay below the cameraPreview.